# Show icons in DataGrid rows when Item meet certain conditions

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, icons, rows

I have a WPF DataGrid that has 3 columns. The 1st and 2nd are to show icons related to that entry meeting some conditions. The 3rd column is the item's name. My code is as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_Items" DisplayMemberPath="{x:Null}" Margin="5"
          HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" Initialized="DG_Items_Initialized"
          MouseMove="DG_Items_MouseMove" SelectionChanged="DG_Items_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Attachment" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Images/Attachment_16x16.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Images/Comment_16x16.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, the icons (attachment and comment) are `Visibility="Hidden"`. The `ItemSource` is populated dynamically using Entity Framework in a method like the following:

```
public void UpdateDG_Items()
{
    DG_Items.ItemsSource = DB.Item.Where(x => x.CodTipoItem == codTipoItemSelecionado && x.SituacaoRegistro != 9)
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.NomeItem).ToList();
    DG_Items.DisplayMemberPath = "ItemName";
    DG_Items.SelectedValuePath = "CodItem";
}
```

I want to show the icons only in the rows that have Items which have an attachment, or comment, or both. I didn't manage to make a trigger in XAML.

Comment: How can you tell if item has attachment or comment? Is there property like `HasComment` / `HasAttachment` against the item?

Comment: I check if Comment != null, then I show the icon. The Attachment table have relationship with the Item table so I can check it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use Converter to do that, like so:

this in your view's xaml file

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:<YourProjectName>.Converters"
```

this is your converter:

```
class TrueToVisibilityVisible : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden; 
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //you could implement this if you wil use it ;-)
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And this is how you use it:
in your Datagrid

```
<Image Source="Images/Comment_16x16.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

replace with this

```
<Image Source="Images/Comment_16x16.png" Visibility="{Binding <PropertyToBind>, Converter={StaticResource <converterName>}}"/>
```

BTW this is how you declare it for use in your View's Resources

```
<converter:TrueToVisibilityVisible x:Key="<converterName>"/>
```

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use "triggers": "data trigger"(Bind it to the value of the first column) and "Event Trigger" to custom your datagrid columns visibility.